# OpenVPN multiple internal IP

Tags: openvpn

I have an OpenVPN server up and running:

```
$ ip addr show tun0
3: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    link/none
    inet 10.8.0.1/16 brd 10.8.255.255 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I'd like to assign additional internal IP to the same interface. It's possible to do it temporary with `ip command`:

```
$ sudo ip addr add 10.9.0.1 dev tun0
```

After running this command, IP is added to this interface and it's possible to bind services to it:

```
$ ip addr show tun0
3: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    link/none
    inet 10.8.0.1/16 brd 10.8.255.255 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.9.0.1/32 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

But how to make these changes permanent? I can't find corresponding configuration options. I'm not sure if it could be done with `/etc/network/interfaces`, since `tun0` isn't mentioned there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your openvpn config:

```
script-security 2
up ip addr add 10.9.0.1 dev tun0
```

Or create an invidual script with `ip` command and use this after `up` in config.

Comment: Thanks! It worked as an individual script. Apparently, `up` command expects only a single argument and quotes don't help.